# Universal ZFC set theory?

Tags: set-theory

What would consequences be of a model $M$ of Zermelo-Fraenkel-Choice set theory that is universal in the sense that any other model is isomorphic to a transitive subclass of $M$? Any impact on large cardinals or forcing?

Added (2020,8,16): It is known that a model with a measurable cardinal has an elementary extension. The universal model has no extensions, so presumably no measurable cardinal.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by one theory being a transitive subclass of another theory? It sounds as if you're conflating theories with classes.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I think he means a model M of ZFC such that any other model is isomorphic to a transitive subclass of M.

Comment: What about ill-founded models?

Comment: He could ask for a universal well-founded model and a universal ill-founded model, no?

Comment: What would be a plausible example of an impact on forcing?

Comment: @Alec No.${{}}$

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I don’t follow? Is ${{}}$ a counterexample to asking for one of each?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Ah, the ${{}}$ was just to get over the character limit — could you please elaborate on why we can’t ask for one of each?

Comment: It may also be interesting to ask for a 'minimal' universal model, i.e. a model $N$ of ZFC such that any other model $N'$ contains an isomorphic copy of $N$ as a transitive subclass.  (we may also want elementary embeddings so first-order statements are preserved)

Comment: Today's edit of the question makes it even less clear. The obvious elementary extension of a model $M$ with a measurable cardinal, namely the ultrapower of $M$ with respect to a countably complete ultrafilter, is isomorphic to a transitive submodel of $M$. The edit does suggest that the question was intended to be about well-founded models; otherwise measurability wouldn't be relevant to the existence of an elementary extension.

Comment: @AndreasBlass  The question is about well-founded models. It was my understanding that "foundation" is one of the axioms of ZFC (cf Jech 2003 book)

Comment: "Foundation" is indeed an axiom of ZFC, but it doesn't imply that all models of ZFC are well-founded. It only ensures that the sets that lack minimal elements (the counterexamples to well-foundedness) are not elements of the model.